# C++ remove trailing new line from text file

Tags: c++, file-io, newline, trim

Is there a way in C++ to remove/trim a trailing new line from a text file?

For example

```
content content
content content
content content
<- this line in the text file is empty and needs to go ->
```

Comment: Yes, but I'd suggest a higher level language. Perhaps python, which would make this ever so easy. How many files need to have this done?

Comment: Are you sure that line actually exists and is not an artifact of your editor. If the last line with content is terminated with '\n' then an editor may display a blank last line even if that line contains zero data.

Comment: I didn't even think of using '\n'. I was using endl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! One way to do it would be to [read the file to a std::string](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=353162)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

 // Add this code inside your main() function
std::ifstream ifs("filename.txt");      
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

and then use any of the techniques described here:

[C++ Remove new line from multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488775/c-remove-new-line-from-multiline-string)

then you could overwrite the file with the new result. Of course, this approach ain't practical when dealing with very large files (let's say, 2GB) but such thing is not a constraint according to your original question.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581539/how-to-identify-a-new-line-in-c) also has great material on detecting new lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
ifstream fin("input.txt");
vector<string> vs;
string s;
while(getline(fin,s))
    vs.push_back(s);
fin.close();

ofstream fout("input.txt");
for(vector<string>::iterator it = vs.begin(); it != vs.end(); ++it)
{
    if(it != vs.begin())
        fout << '\n';
    fout << *it;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient method would be to seek to the end of the file and move the end-of-file pointer backwards.  Unfortunately this is not portable because there is no standard way of setting the end-of-file pointer in either the C or C++ standard libraries.  You need to use a platform-specific function such as [`SetEndOfFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows or [`ftruncate`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) on POSIX.  For example:

```
void RemoveFinalNewline(const char *filename)
{
#if defined(_WIN32)
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        ;  // handle error

    LARGE_INTEGER fileSize;
    if(GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &fileSize) == 0)
        ;  // handle error
    if(fileSize.QuadPart < 2)
        ;  // this case is left as an exercise to the reader

    LARGE_INTEGER newFilePtr;
    newFilePtr.QuadPart = -2;
    if(SetFilePointerEx(hFile, &newFilePtr, NULL, FILE_END) == 0)
        ;  // handle error

    char lastTwoBytes[2];
    if(ReadFile(hFile, lastTwoBytes, 2, NULL, NULL) == 0)
        ;  // handle error

    if(lastTwoBytes[1] == '\n')
    {
        fileSize.QuadPart--;
        if(lastTwoBytes[0] == '\r')
            fileSize.QuadPart--;
        if(SetFilePointerEx(hFile, &fileSize, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) == 0)
            ;  // handle error
        if(SetEndOfFile(hFile) == 0)
            ;  // handle error
        // Success!
    }
    // else the file didn't end in a newline

    CloseHandle(hFile);  // and we're done
#else  // POSIX case; the non-Windows, non-POSIX case is left as an exercise
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1)
        ;  // handle error

    off_t fileSizeMinus1 = lseek(fd, -1, SEEK_END);
    if(fileSizeMinus1 == (off_t)-1)
        ;  // handle error

    // We're assuming that a newline is a bare LF '\n' here.  The CRLF case
    // is left as an exercise (hint: see the Windows case above)
    char lastChar;
    if(read(fd, &lastChar, 1) != 1)
        ;  // handle error

    if(lastChar == '\n')
    {
        if(ftruncate(fd, fileSizeMinus1) == -1)
            ;  // handle error
        // else success!
    }
    // else the file does not end in a newline

    close(fd);  // and we're done
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++11 or higher - removes trailing *whitespaces* (newlines, tabs, spaces, ...):

```
std::string readAndTrimTrailingSpaces(std::string const & filePath)
{
    std::ifstream file(filePath);
    std::string   buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, {});

    while (!buffer.empty() && std::isspace(buffer.back()))
        buffer.pop_back();

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Apparently that second argument to `std::string` [can be shortened to `{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/116177/6243352).

Answer (score 0):

You need to read all the contents from file, and write the contents again in such a way that no empty line exists, or the way you want.

Comment: Right right, that's what I figured. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: i cannot tell you until i know exact file format. read on c++ fstream: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/

Comment: The file format is exactly as above, just with more lines of more varying content

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple filter, applied as in:

```
remove_empty_last_line < input.txt > output.txt
```

Or, you can create your own file input stream ala:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream myin(filename);
```

Then, the code would resemble (untested)...

```
char c, d, e;

if (cin.get(c))
    if (cin.get(d))
    {
        while (cin.get(e))
        {
            cout << d;
            c = d;
            d = e;
        }
        if (c != '\n' || d != '\n')
            cout << d;
    }
    else
        cout << c;
```

(Substitute myin for cin if desired, then myin.close()).  No need to use std::strings for something so simple: they just slow everything down.  One of the great strengths of C (and hence C++) is being able to efficiently process data a character at a time.