# How to ignore newline characters when reading file in list format

Tags: c++, newline, ifstream

I am trying to read a file with a list of titles and authors, and I need to be able to ignore the newline character that separates each line in the file.

For example, my .txt file might have a list like this:

```
The Selfish Gene
Richard Dawkins
A Brave New World
Aldous Huxley
The Sun Also Rises
Ernest Hemingway
```

I have to use parallel arrays to store this info, and then be able to format the data like so:

```
The Selfish Gene (Richard Dawkins)
```

I was trying to use `getline` to read the data, but when I go to format the title and author, I get this:

```
The Selfish Gene
(Richard Dawkins
)
```

How do I ignore the newline character when I read in the list from the file?

This is what I have so far:

```
    int loadData(string pathname)
    {
    string bookTitle[100];
    string bookAuthor[100];
    ifstream inFile;
    int count = -1; //count number of books
    int i; //for variable

    inFile.open(pathname.c_str());
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        {
            if(inFile)
            {
                getline(inFile, bookTitle[i]);
                getline(inFile, bookAuthor[i]);
                count++;
            }
        }
        inFile.close();
        return count;
    }
```

---

EDIT:

This is my output function:

```
    void showall(int count)
    {
        int j; //access array up until the amount of books
        for(j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
             cout << bookTitle[j] << " (" << bookAuthor[j] << ")";
             cout << endl;
        }    
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `getline` should strip the newline character. Perhaps you're using a DOS file on a UNIX machine, and the carriage return character is slipping through and being interpreted as a newline?

Comment: This code behaves badly if either call to `std::getline` fails. Just an FYI.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581539/how-to-identify-a-new-line-in-c

Comment: What does your output code look like?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I added my output code to the body of my question.  I am using a mac, compiling with Xcode.  Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

As @Potatoswatter says, `std::getline` normally does strip the newline character. If newlines are still getting through, you're probably using a system which uses `\n` for it's newlines, yet your file has `\r\n` newlines.

Just remove the extra newlines after they get added to the string. You can do that with something like:

```
s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), std::not1(std::isspace)).base(), s.end());
```

or similar. You'll find `std::find_if` in `<algorithm>`, `std::isspace` in `<clocale>`, and `std::not1` in `<functional>`.

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT! The problem was the file that I was reading.  I copy and pasted the file with the titles and authors from the .txt my instructor gave us into a new .txt file, and now it works fine the way I had it!  Thank you everyone for the help!!